# Uploaded binaries not showing in prerelease list

Tags: xcode6, app-store-connect

I archived, and submitted my test binary to iTunesConnect via Xcode.
Normally, the build is added to a long list of previous builds, it processes for 5 minutes or so, and then becomes editable.  At this point I supply release notes.

Now, the entire list is gone.

I tried re-submitting the binary, but got the duplicate version error (which is correct.)

Has Apple changed the location where testflight binaries are listed?

Comment: I just experienced this same problem too. Seems like an issue with iTunes Connect itself and hopefully will be resolved soon.

Comment: **Temporary glitch, the site is working as usual now.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your iOS Developer Program Membership is going to expire very soon?

This happened to me once.